# How to change background of the app?

Tags: java, android-studio

Is there a way to change background directly in the app? (!not homescreen wallpaper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the layout that its background will be changed. I guess you have a LinearLayout, so add an id to the layout (if it is not exist):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id=@+id/parentLayout>
```

Then you can change the background in Java with:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_background);
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

i have a link for you is easy to change background app.
Try something like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDKuWIlSNJE